# Delete prepopulated database

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, populate

I want to delete the prepopulated database, in order to shrink the size of my app.
I tried to remove it but it seems I cannot touch the bundle of the app.

I got this error when I tried:
(Cocoa error 513.)"The operation couldn’t be completed. Operation not permitted"

Thanks you.

Comment: Could you add some code and tell us what kind of database is ?

Comment: It's a .DB database I tried: 
``
`[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:BDD_FILENAME] error:nil];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app bundle folder cannot be modified. It's read only.

You can delete the file through an app update. Delete it from the bundle, then submit the update.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify your app's bundle.  It's read-only.